# Spring JPA- DB2 ZOS - Observing -104 error during shut down of DB2 LPAR

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, db2, db2-zos

We are seeing the db2 -104 issue during db2 lpar graceful down testing, And it looks to be "SELECT 1" query is being executed during the lpar testing and this is only observed in DB2 log.

> SQLerror, DSNT408I SQLCODE = -104, ERROR: ILLEGAL SYMBOL
> "".
>
> Query Executed : SELECT 1

Spring version : 2.1.7

IBM Db2 Jar version : db2jcc4.jar

Dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect

Any lead on how to stop or override this query being fired? We run on liberty server and excluded tomcat related dependencies as well.

Comment: What is the version of db2jcc4.jar and on which operating-system (and verison) runs the liberty server (and what is the verison of the liberty server).

Comment: Check your connection pool configuration, specifically the query used to check connection validity. `SELECT 1` is not valid syntax in Db2.

Comment: Hi We are using wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.12 and db2Jcc is 4.19.49

Comment: regarding connection pool we have configured xml with connectionManager for db2 and same has been configured in the wlp server.xml. <connectionManager minPoolSize="25"
                           maxPoolSize="50"
                           connectionTimeout="5000"
                           maxIdleTime="200"
                           purgepolicy="FailingConnectionOnly"
                           reaptime="-1"/>

Comment: Is there any configuration file with `validationQuery="SELECT 1"` ? Search carefully. That is relevant for other rdbms, but not for Db2.

Comment: Hi, There is no validation query, in spring 2.1.7 there is no validationQuery property I can override. Also as jcc is configured as driver, just trying to understand how come spring default query can run and Is there anyway to override it

Comment: Hi, Can someone help me to understand why the Spring Jpa default queries excuted while we use IBM JCC jar? And validation-query is used only by tomcat or dbcp2 hope both of these are not used in db2, so, not sure where is this query getting fired from spring framework. any leads to solve this would be a great help please.

Comment: any help to even run some debug for our analysis? ran out of ideas